# Water Not Being Emitted and the Domain Stays a Cube when Baked in Water Simulator

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, physics, fluid-simulation

I don't know why this is happening, but my water simulator is not working. Here is my setup:
[image: Setup]

The selected object as well as the other big object are both obstacles. There is a rectangle at the top as the inflow and another at the bottom as the outflow. The whole thing is surrounded with a cube that is the domain (it is hidden now). Basically, it is a slab then a drop then a slab. A side view looks like this:

```
000000000  
x       0
ooooooo 0
      o 0
      o 00000000
      o        y
      oooooooooo
```

o - Object 1, obstacle
0 - Object 2, obstacle
x - Object 3, inflow
y - Object 4, outflow

And a cube as the domain surrounding all of that. I have the default settings on all except for no slip and some velocity on the inflow and water on the domain for viscosity. When I bake the domain just stays a cube. What would cause this?

The blender file:
[image]

Comment: Could you upload your .blend file to [here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: @ShadyPuck done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share the file just to make sure, but you can try to set the volume initialization on all the objects to both, and make the domain object larger.

Comment: One of those seemed to have done it